# How to search a file in the folder

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net & Window application

I want to get a list of file from the folder

File name like = **FTSDD06???035????????????.FTR**

Tried Code

```
Public Function GetFileNames(ByVal sFolder As String, ByVal sFileNamePattern As String, _
            ByVal iMaxFiles As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Return GetFileNames(sFolder, sFileNamePattern, iMaxFiles, False) 'False=include empty files
    End Function
```

Above code is not working, not getting anything

I want to get all the files from the folder where filename contain **FTSDD06???035????????????.FTR*

Need code help

Comment: it is recursing.  `Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp", "c???_???_???_???.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)` works fine for me

Comment: @Plutonix: No it's not. External GetFileNames has 3 parameters, the one it's calling has 4. We just don't have the full code.

Comment: Ah! I didnt notice the param count.  Still seems dicey to name a function the same as a NET function.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make certain you are calling the NET method to get files as in `Directory.GetFiles` rather than a local method of the same name.  At a minimum it should make the code less confusing; without looking carefully, it looks like it should be recursing.

```
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp", "c???_???_??x_???.jpg",
          SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

This works for me to find the one and only file which matches that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

this code will help you to get Files and will teach you some-how to use "List(Of Type)" :

```
    Dim Files_With_Same_Name As New List(Of String)
    For Each file_with_Name In IO.Directory.GetFiles("Your Path", "", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
        If file_with_Name.Contains("FTSDD06") And file_with_Name.Contains("035") And file_with_Name.Contains(".FTR") Then
            Files_With_Same_Name.Add(file_with_Name)
        End If
    Next
    Dim Files() As String = Files_With_Same_Name.ToArray
```

**NOTE** : 
the **IF** condition in this case is  used to find any file with the parts of name given .